# Material UI in Intel XDK

Tags: intel-xdk, material-ui

I am new with App development using Intel XDK. I need to incorporate material UI in my app which is developed using Intel XDK. Please give me a solution with examples.. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be accomplished by using any material design UI, a popular one being:

[Materialize](http://materializecss.com/mobile.html)

Intel XDK takes web applications made with CSS/JS/HTML and wraps them as "native applications" so they can be distributed as phone apps. Intel XDK comes packaged with some example projects that help show this process. I recommend checking out their ionic framework example to start.